# Lenovo Thinkpad P51 freezes randomly and frequently on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: freeze

The random and frequent freezes occurred two days ago after a system update (I don't know what exactly was updated).

**Edit**: after the system update, the settings did not show up. I then checked the driver used - it was Nouveau. So I switched to nvidia-driver-470. (But it turned out that this had nothing to do with settings disappearing.) I don't know if the current freeze is related to nvidia driver.

Before this, even under heavy load, the system would not freeze and only the fan would spin very fast. But now it freezes at login or freezes when I open a terminal or click on some applications after a fresh login when no other processes are running. The keyboard and mouse stop to respond and hard shutdown is the only way to get out of the situation. For the last days, it has occurred 4 or 5 times per day, without any earlier signals.

My generic kernel is `4.15.0-151-generic`.

Does it make sense to update the kernel? Does it have anything to do with the nvidia driver? How to further trouble shoot this?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Are there any messages in `/var/log/syslog` that might point to the problem?

Comment: I could not identify any error messages that could be obviously connected to the freeze before it occurs.

Comment: I suspect that it is related to nvidia driver. I have asked in Nvidia forum. Will report when updates come.

Comment: This machine is well known for a problem with the connector on the motherboard, that connects the SSD to the computer. Soldering done by Lenovo is very bad, resulting in intermittently and random issues. Just check the solderings of it. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WrOcfmDYyT0